# Rational cohomology of p-adic general linear groups

Tags: lie-algebras, group-cohomology, profinite-groups, lie-algebra-cohomology, exterior-algebra

I wanted to compute the cohomology ring $H^*(GL_n(\mathbb{Z}_p); \mathbb{Q}_p)$ (with $p$ fixed prime as usual). I found some incomplete notes stating that the computation should go as follows.

First we use a theorem by Lazard stating that for $G$ a compact p-adic analytic group we have
\begin{equation} H^*(G; \mathbb{Q}_p)\cong H^*(\mathfrak{g};\mathbb{Q}_p)^G \end{equation}
where $\mathfrak{g}$ is the rationalization of the logarithm algebra associated to an open subset of $G$ which is a uniformly powerful pro-p group. The most modern reference I could find is "Cohomology of p-adics Analytic Groups" of P. Symonds and T. Weigel, theorem 5.2.4. This algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ can also be identified with the tangent space of $G$ with the usual Lie bracket.

If $G=GL_n(\mathbb{Z}_p)$ we have $\mathfrak{g}\cong p.M_n(\mathbb{Z}_p)\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}_p}\mathbb{Q}_p$ where $p.M_n(\mathbb{Z}_p)$ is the module of matrices which are multiples of $p$: it has a Lie bracket induced by its algebra structure.

First of all we have to show there is a bijection between the following sets.
Let $P^d$ be the set of functions $f\colon p.M_n(\mathbb{Z}_p) \rightarrow \mathbb{Q}_p$ which are homogeneous polynomial of degree $d$ in the entries of the argument matrix. Let $S^d$ be the set of symmetric multilinear maps $g \colon (p.M_n(\mathbb{Z}_p))^d \rightarrow \mathbb{Q}_p$. The map $S^d \rightarrow P^d$ is given just by $g\mapsto f$ with $f(m)=g(m,m,\dots,m)$ while the inverse is given by polarization
\begin{equation} g(m_1,\dots,m_d)= \frac{(-1)^d}{d!}\sum_I(-1)^{|I|}f\bigg( \sum_{i \in I}m_i\bigg)  \end{equation}
where the indexing set $I$ ranges over all the subsets of $\{1,2,\dots,d \}$.

This bijection is nothing particular to the situation: it should hold if we were to replace $\mathbb{Q}_p$ with a a field $K$ of characteristic zero and $p.M_n(\mathbb{Z}_p)$ with $\text{End}(M)$ for any $M$ finite dimensional $K$-vector space.

We now define $f_k\colon p.M_n(\mathbb{Z}_p)\rightarrow \mathbb{Q}_p$  to be the element of $P^k$ sending $u$ to the coefficient of $t^{n-k}$ in the characteristic polynomial $\det(u-It)$. Using the bijection above we obtain $g_k \in S^k$ and extending by $\mathbb{Q}_p$-linearity we get a symmetric multilinear map $g_k\colon \mathfrak{g}^k \rightarrow \mathbb{Q}_p$.

Using this we define a map $\mathfrak{g}^{\otimes (2k-1)}\rightarrow \mathbb{Q}_p$ by
\begin{equation} u_1\otimes \dots \otimes u_{2k-1}\mapsto g_k([u_1,u_2], [u_3, u_4], \dots, u_{2k-1}) \end{equation}
and by antisymmetrizing we get an element $a_{2k-1}\in \Lambda^{2k-1}\mathfrak{g}^{\ast}$.

The mentioned notes claim without proof that these elements are cocycles of the Chevalley complex computing $H^*(\mathfrak{g}; \mathbb{Q}_p)$ and in fact $H^*(\mathfrak{g}; \mathbb{Q}_p)\cong \Lambda[a_1,\dots, a_{2n-1}]$.

I managed to show that these $a_{2k-1}$ are in fact cocyles, from the invariance of $f_k$ under conjugation it is clear that if we prove $H^*(\mathfrak{g}; \mathbb{Q}_p)$ is the exterior algebra generated by these elements then it coincides with $H^*(GL_n(\mathbb{Z}_p); \mathbb{Q}_p)$.

But I could not prove that these $a_{2k-1}$'s are actually generators and my question would be if you know how to do this. I thought that maybe I have to employ a spectral sequence coming from a filtration of the Chevalley complex but I could not find a nice multiplicative filtration doing the job.

I computed explicitly the Chevalley complex for $n=2$ to see if the claim holds and indeed it was confirmed true for this case, even if I do not see why it should be true in general.

Since this computation is considered folklore it should be written somewhere, but I did not have any luck in finding a source. Do you know a reference for this? Also is there a good reference for computations of cohomology (rational or not) groups of pro-p groups and analytic p-adic groups? I mentioned before the paper by Symonds and Weigel but it deals more with the homological foundations of continuous cohomology rather than concrete examples.